# Пролистывающийся список из табличек без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: ajax

Доброго всем дня.

Есть БД/Таблица, в которой порядка 50 записей, и из нее выводится 3 записи (14, 15, 16 - каждая в виде маленькой таблички). Собственно по бокам таблицы кнопки +/-, смысл которых в пролистывании выбираемых записей из таблиты. примитивным образом страница перезагружается (загружает уже 15, 16 17 запись если нажать - ). Хочется сделать через что либо без перезагрузки страницы. В плане Ajax - вооружен лишь теорией, и не смог самостоятельно написать скрипт.

Может ли кто помочь советом, или кодом, как сделать, чтобы без перезагрузки страницы произвести новый выбор данных?

p.s. Делаю первый шаг в Ajax.

Comment: судя по вашему нику раскладку вы тоже переключать не умеете :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим есть таблица и 2 кнопки:

```
<table id="data">
</table>
<a id="prev" class="button">Предыдущая</a>
<a id="next" class="button">Следующая</a>
```

Подключаем JQuery. Код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
var startid=1;

$(".button").click(function() {
  startid = ($(this).id()=="next") ? startid+=3 : startid-=3
  if (startid > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "get_row.php",
      dataType : "text",
      data: {startid: startid},                     
      success: function (data) { 
        //Тут обрабатываем и выводим данные. Если в пхп сгенерим уже готовый хтмл код, то просто аппендим его в таблицу
        //$("#data").append(data);
        //для теста выведем их алертом
        alert (data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });
  } else {
    startid=1;
    alert("Достигнуто начало записей");
  }
});
```

В пхп файле get_row.php мы должны получить данные `$start_id = $_POST['startid']`, обработать их и вывести на экран результат в виде `<tr><td>..</td><td>..</td></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Ну на клик по плюсу-минусу я бы сделал обработчик события, который бы отправлял на сервер данные о нужном интервале данных при помощи `XmlHttpRequest`, ну а как выбирать данные на серваке - это уже кому как удобно. Можно, например, использовать для этого `PagedDataSource`. Говорят, помогает в этом случае. После выборки из БД сериализовать это всё в JSON, возвращать JSON клиенту и собственно выводить нужные тебе данные в таблицу на странице при помощи JavaScript =)